# In Next.js project I get the following error: "Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm encountering an issue with my website which consists of two main sections: a Header and a body. Upon the initial loading of the page, I'm not facing any hydration errors. However, after the page is loaded and I perform a reload, I encounter a hydration error specifically within the Header section, displaying 'Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server' error message.

I'm working on a Next.js project where I utilize useQuery to fetch data and generate the Header dynamically. It works perfectly fine upon the initial load, but upon reloading the page, the data temporarily returns as {} (an empty object), and then gets updated properly, triggering a hydration error.

[Hydration failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPifI.png)

I've tried numerous solutions found online but haven't had any success. Although setting ssr:false for the component and dynamically importing it resolves the issue, it's not the desired approach for me.

[temp solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn2jJ.png)

I think the problem is caused by the active Company variable from this component in the Header. Because if no data arrives when the page is reloaded, an empty object is returned temporarily.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

import dynamicRoute from '@/miscellaneous/constant';
import useCompany from '@/utils/hooks/company/useCompany';
import useMutations from '@/utils/hooks/mutations/useMutations';

import LinkDropdown from '../LinkDropdown';

function CompaniesDropDown() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { userCompanies, activeCompany, isLoading } = useCompany();

  .... (some code in here)

  return (
    <div className="relative flex items-center">
      <LinkDropdown
        style={{
          fontWeight: '400',
        }}
        checkedId={activeCompany?.id}
        color="black"
        link
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        onAddClick={handleCreateCompany}
        items={items}
        header={activeCompany?.name || (router.query?.company as string)}
        onLinkClick={(item: any) => console.log('route to', item)}
        text="Add new company"
        direction="bottom left"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CompaniesDropDown;
```

Is there an alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the structure of the *LinkDropdown* component? In most cases, this error is caused by the bad semantic structure of HTML DOM tree. For example: `<p>` nested in another `<p>` tag. By the way your solution is one of the official ways to fix this error: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I already checked the documents before.